How to configure World Wide Web Publishing service as Generic service in Microsoft Failover Clustering
When I try to configure a role - Generic service for World wide Web Publishing service, it doesn't start at all
Remains in pending state
I have web applications that will be hosted in IIS with multiple application pools,
I'm trying to install the files in a shared disk in Failover clustering so one node will be active at a time and if one goes down the next becomes the active node
so trying to achieve the same for IIS, Source files in Shared disk and during configuration I can point that storage and when switched the same to switch to the another node, both the IIS service and Storage
File server role is ok, but unsure how to setup IIS in failover cluster

The steps haven't changed much ever since IIS 7, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-authentication-authorization/configure-w3svc-wsfc, so if you hit any issue you need to first carefully review if you missed any. No one here can easily help without accessing your machines.

How do you configure common services in your cluster? Among other things, you need to set up dependencies and test failover.
